# что означает && справа от объявления метода?

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, rvalue

Вот метод, который возвращает rvalue ссылку, но что означает && справа от имени метода?

```
return_type &&result() &&{
}
```

Comment: Что он применяется к rvalue объекту.

Comment: @Harry, тоесть данный метод можно вызывать только у rvalue объекта?

Answer (score 4):

Это значит, что функция-член вызывается только для rvalue-объекта. Например:

```
struct Test
{
    void f() && {};
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.f();        // Ошибка
    Test().f();   // Компилируется
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/DDY9Sa

Точно так же единственный `&` говорит о применимости функции-члена к lvalue объекту:

```
struct Test
{
    void f() & {};
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.f();        // Компилируется
    Test().f();   // Ошибка
}
```